# "IOSurface seed changed" warnings in console

Tags: macos, logs, console

In Console.app, in the System logging section, I'm seeing messages like this, at a rate of roughly one per second:

> 19:09:38 kernel: Warning: IOSurface 00000236 seed changed while owned by an accelerator 00000003: 00000304 -> 00000146

What is this, and can I make it stop?  It's making it almost impossible to read anything else in the log.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/IOSurfaceAPI_header_reference/Reference/reference.html), IOSurface is an API being called that allow applications to move complex image decompression and draw logic into a separate process to enhance security.

Apps that share media utilize this API, such as Messages or QuickTime.

I've read that this issue can arise when using a VPN, but I can't seem to corroborate that at the moment.

Comment: I do use Screen Sharing to access another machine sometimes, but I get these messages even when it isn't running.

Comment: The obvious question is: if it is caused by an app doing something funny with a kernel call, is there a way to figure out what app made this kernel call?

Comment: possible it is happen by a malicious made quartz composer plugin. had this kind of feedback in console everytime i made misstakes while programming a plugin there. specially when working with video input from facetime camera.